# Prove that there are only finitely many rational numbers $p/q$ satisfying $|\frac{p}{q}-\sqrt[d]{b}|\leq \frac{C}{q^3}$.

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-approximation

This is a problem from Silverman & Tate's Rational Points on Elliptic Curves. The following is the Diophantine Approximation theorem by Thue which is proved in Chapter 5:

> **Theorem**. Let $b$ be a positive integer which is not a perfect cube, and let $\beta=\sqrt[3]{b}$. Let $C$ be a fixed positive constant. Then there are only finitely many pairs of integers $(p,q)$ with $q>0$ which satisfy the inequality
>   $$\left|\frac{p}{q}-\beta\right|\leq \frac{C}{q^3}.$$

The following is an exercise which I am stuck at:

> **Exercise 5.9.** Let $d\geq 3$ be an integer, and let $b$ be an integer that is not a perfect $d$th power. For any constant $C$, prove that there are only finitely many rational numbers $p/q$ satisfying the inequality
>   $$\left|\frac{p}{q}-\sqrt[d]{b}\right|\leq \frac{C}{q^3}.$$

I can prove this statement using the same argument provided in the book to prove the above theorem, **IF** $d$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\beta$. The proof constructs an auxiliary polynomial, proves its partial derivatives vanish at $(\beta,\beta)$, proves it is small at around $(\beta,\beta)$, and some of its derivative does not vanish.

The proof is too long, I cannot restate it here. So I'm hoping someone familiar with this method could help me with the case when $d$ is not the degree of the minimal polynomial.

Alternatively, is there a way to prove this exercise using Thue's theorem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Let $r$ be the smallest integer such that $b^{r/d}$ is an integer. Then $r \geq 2$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial of $b^{1/d}$. You can then apply the same method.

Comment: @Aravind: Thank you! I'll try that.